# Why drupal_render($form) does not render correctly RADIOS #type?

Tags: php, drupal, forms, drupal-6

I'm trying to use **[drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_render_form/6)** to render a single form element. I can successfully render elements of `'#type' => 'textfield' or 'radio' or 'whatever'`.

When I try to render an element of `'#type' => 'radios'` something goes wrong. I can't find out why but the radios simple won't show.

```
$options = array(
    '0' => 'no option',
    '1' => 'option 1',
    '2' => 'option 2',
    '3' => 'option 3',
    '4' => 'option 4',
    '5' => 'option 5'
);

$form['radiosinput'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'radios',
    '#title'            => 'radios title',
    '#description'      => 'radios description',
    '#default_value'    => 0,
    '#options'          => $options,
    '#required'         => TRUE,
);

var_dump( drupal_render($form) );

// string(257) "<div class="form-item">
//     <label>radios title: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
//     <div class="form-radios"></div>
//     <div class="description">radios description</div>
//     </div>
// "
```

**Anyone knows what's the problem and the fix/workaround?**
Is there any known problem with rendering radios or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't render form elements without a form because the the radios element has a process callback of form_process_radios() that is called only when used with the form API.

You might be able to try something like:

```
$form['radiosinput'] = expand_radios($form['radiosinput']);
return drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: `form_process_*` are D7 specific. I'm looking for a D6 solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, then use $form['radiosinput'] = expand_radios($form['radiosinput']);

Comment: please update your answer with that info, and I'll accept it! :) `drupal_render(expand_radios($form['radiosinput']));` did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For D7 use form_process_checkboxes()

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar an hour ago. Your code pasted into my form works just fine.

Try

drupal_get_form('your_form_id');

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not rendering a form, just that specific element... The code also works fine if I include it in a form.

Comment: @andre matos It might be helpful to know why you're rendering radio buttons without a form.

Comment: Can you run the form element through the theme layer instead? theme_radios() or something...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with the checkboxes element I wanted to render in a table. I found your answer a little bit to late.

So for all other searching how to render a checkboxes element with [drupal_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/6) and [expand_checkboxes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/expand_checkboxes/6):

```
$form['test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Test'),
  '#description' => t('The description appears usually below the checkboxes.'),
  '#options' => array(1,2,3,4),
);

drupal_render(expand_checkboxes($form['test']));
```

Comment: What's the equivalent of this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

I might add, that in D6 you need to add #parents => array() to the radios element.
if no, expand_radios will throw an error, in my case. Drupal 6.22